# React android Facebook login page UI issues

Tags: react-native

I am using facebook login in my react-native app. I am able to login and perform all operations successfully. But the UI login screen displayed by facebook doesnt sit correctly in the screen. I am attaching the screenshot here. Do we have to set some styling anywhere? Please guide.

The IOS facebook login looks good. pls refer to the screenshot attached..

[image: Android facebook login screen]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGqKD.jpg)

Comment: Screenshot looks ok, what is the problem?

Comment: Hi @Cherniv the UI doesnt look good. The close icon is placed properly.The login screen should be occupying full space.

Comment: @Cherniv.. pls find the attached IOS login screen for facebook. It looks great